# How to distinguish programatically created charts/shapes from all charts/shapes on the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, shapes, excel-charts

I am looking for a way to distinguish between the charts created by my code and the charts created "manually" by the user.
Using `chart.name` would work if I would set a specific name_prefix or something for the charts but this property is of no use to me as the names can be changed dynamically by the user. I have thought about looking at chart like at shape and change its ID, but no luck with it either.
I have checked chart/shape object model and I cannot find a property, which I could use to somehow distinguish "my charts" from all charts on a sheet collection.

The general idea is that I create a chart with VBA and when user activates it, `chart.activate` event opens a userform. This userform should open when user activates chart created by my code and not on activating ANY chart on the sheet. I know how to do everything except how to distinguish the charts.

Any ideas how this could be done?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have also thought about adding some information to series names, again, prefix type of info. That would work, but once again - it could be easily changed by the end user and this is what I would like to avoid.

Comment: Add a reference to the chart objects you create programtically to a scripting dictionary.  You might even be able to use Varptr to get a memory address that you can use as a key but I am unsure as to how often VBA/EWxcel might move things around in the background thus invalidating an value obtained by Varptr.

Comment: Interesting idea. I have red about dictionaries but I have no used them before. How would that work? I imagine I add the specific key of the chart to dictionary. But if I am not mistaken I would have to tie this key with specific chart element to "decode" it later? Where would that dictionary be stored? Could it be retrieved between sessions, for example, after closing workbooks?

Comment: If you need to store information between sessions that's a whole different ballgame.  II such a case I'd follow @rchardtallent's proposal.

Comment: @freeflow Got it. Thank you for the idea though. I will definately look into it as this is a part of VBA I had not stepped into yet :)

Comment: Also have a look at Chart.CodeName property (Excel)

Comment: I cannot assign or retrieve Chart.CodeName property from embedded chart. Is this property not related to chart worksheets only?

Comment: Did you activate chart events, or did you assign a macro to each created charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be good if you posted the code you use. I (only) can suppose that you activated charts events.

Please, try the next way, which should work with events activated, or not:

1. Copy the next code in a standard module. It is a `Sub` which will be assigned to all created charts. It can be used instead of (existing) events, or with events working:

```
Sub CreatedChart()
   Dim ch As Chart
   Set ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Application.Caller).Chart
   'you can call the form in discussion here...
   Select Case ch.Parent.Name
    Case "CrChart1", "CrChart2"
        MsgBox "Here you can do something in case of Chart 1 or Chart 2..."
    Case "CrChart3"
        MsgBox "Here you can do something in case of Chart 3..."
   End Select
End Sub
```

2. Copy the next code in a module, too. It will create charts and assign the above `Sub` to them:

```
Sub testChartsCreate()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, ch As ChartObject, i As Long
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   For i = 1 To 3
        Set ch = ws.ChartObjects.Add(left:=1, _
                    top:=10, width:=100, height:=100)
        ch.Name = "CrChart" & i
        ws.Shapes(ch.Name).OnAction = "CreatedChart"
        ch.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
        'do here all your charts configuration...
   Next i
End Sub
```

3. You can identify which of all existing charts on a sheet **have been created by the above code**. Please, take care to also have some manually created charts, or programmatically, but not by the above code (type), which assigns that specific `Sub`:

```
Sub testIdentifCrCharts()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, ch As ChartObject, i As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here the necessary sheet
   For Each ch In sh.ChartObjects
        Debug.Print ch.Name, isCreatedChart(ch.Chart, sh)
   Next
End Sub

Private Function isCreatedChart(ch As Chart, sh As Worksheet) As Boolean
  If sh.Shapes(ch.Parent.Name).OnAction = "CreatedChart" Then
    isCreatedChart = True
  End If
End Function
```

I used `ch As Chart` like the first function parameter, for the case of Charts to be checked, not `ChartObjects`...

The above solution may look complicated, but it is very easy to be understood and applied, in fact.

Please, test the above suggestion and send some feedback.

Comment: Good idea, I like the approach and the creativity. I have looked at OnAction property but I had no idea how to use it. One question though - can you somehow apply value to OnAction property without actually running a macro? Have you used it with "empty macro" to simply assign a value to this property, which could be checked later on? I just wonder what potential issues I might have with this "empty" approach

Comment: @Rafał Kowalski: The main idea was to answer your question. I mean, I used the chart shape `OnAction` property to differentiate the charts created using the above code, from the other ones on the sheet. But it can be two in one, if needed... Using `Application.Caller` you can identify the pressed chart and do something according to its name, using a single assigned macro for all of them. I will edit the above `CreatedChart()` `Sub` and show you how can it be used instead of an event.

Comment: @Rafał Kowalski: Updated. Please, click on the charts created with the above code and you will see the result. The using of the `Sub` in this (new) way does not bother the way of code created charts identification. It works exactly in the same way... It is only another facility to replace the chart event.

Answer (score 0):

One potential idea would be to put your magic value in `MailEnvelope.Introduction`. This is a VBA-settable string property you likely won't ever use for its intended purpose, and it isn't exposed in the UI for a user-created chart.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have tried to assign or read value to/from 'MailEnvelope' but I get the run-time error 1004 "Object-defined error". I couldn't get around this and I did not know what this property is for. Could you give me some more hints how would that work? I suppose that when I add value to this property then it would be present "in" this object until it is deleted? And as a result - I should be able to check if selected chart has mailenvelope.introduction = X and if true then do something?